# Error: .eslintrc.json: Configuration for rule "import/no-unresolved" is invalid and should NOT have additional properties

Tags: node.js, json, typescript, npm, eslint

After implement **eslint** and **prettier** together without conflicts, **babel** is added correctly.

I am trying to add absolute paths in ***TypeScript*** using the plugin "***eslint-plugin-module-resolver***", everything fine to compile, transpile or start a server, but I am still getting an error just in eslint only.

Error description - **Should NOT have additional properties** while "npm run lint".

Can someone help me with this issue?! Thanks

**Error #1**

```
npm run lint

> setup@1.0.0 lint
> eslint . --ext .ts .tsx


Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 8.25.0

Error: .eslintrc.json:
        Configuration for rule "import/no-unresolved" is invalid:
        Value {"plugins":["module-resolver/use-alias",{"alias":{"@config":"./src/config","@controllers":"./src/controllers","@services":"./src/services","@models":"./src/models","@routes":"./src/routes","@pages":"./src/pages","@utils":"./src/utils","@middlewares":"./src/middlewares"}}],"caseSensitive":true,"caseSensitiveStrict":false} should NOT have additional properties.
```

**.eslintrc.json**

```
{
      "env": {
        "es2021": true,
        "node": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "prettier"
      ],
      "overrides": [],
      "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
      "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "sourceType": "module",
        "project": "./tsconfig.json"
      },
      "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "module-resolver", "prettier", "import"],
      "rules": {
        "indent": ["error", 2],
        "tabwidth": ["error", 2],
        "linebreak-style": ["error", "unix"],
        "quotes": ["error", "double"],
        "semi": ["error", "always"],
        "trailingComma": ["warn", "none"],
        "prettier/prettier": "error",
        "import/no-unresolved": [
          "error",
          {
            "plugins": [
              "module-resolver",
              {
                "alias": {
                  "@config": "./src/config",
                  "@controllers": "./src/controllers",
                  "@services": "./src/services",
                  "@models": "./src/models",
                  "@routes": "./src/routes",
                  "@pages": "./src/pages",
                  "@utils": "./src/utils",
                  "@middlewares": "./src/middlewares"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "setup",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Nodejs setup using typescript, babel, eslint and prettier",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Gonzalo Cugiani",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "ts-node-dev -r tsconfig-paths/register --respawn src/index.ts",
    "build": "babel src --extensions \".ts, .js\" --out-dir dist --copy-files",
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts .tsx"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/node": "^7.19.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.4",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.14",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.40.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.40.1",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.25.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-module-resolver": "^1.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "targets": {
            "node": "current"
          }
        }
      ],
      "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "module-resolver",
        {
          "alias": {
            "@config": "./src/config",
            "@controllers": "./src/controllers",
            "@services": "./src/services",
            "@models": "./src/models",
            "@routes": "./src/routes",
            "@pages": "./src/pages",
            "@utils": "./src/utils",
            "@middlewares": "./src/middlewares"
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .eslintrc.json, remove 2nd object argument

```
        "import/no-unresolved": [
          "error",
          /* remove this object -> */ {
            "plugins": [
              "module-resolver",
              {
                "alias": {
                  "@config": "./src/config",
                  "@controllers": "./src/controllers",
                  "@services": "./src/services",
                  "@models": "./src/models",
                  "@routes": "./src/routes",
                  "@pages": "./src/pages",
                  "@utils": "./src/utils",
                  "@middlewares": "./src/middlewares"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
```

from "import/no-unresolved" arguments, as error says it should not be there
Generally, the eslint plugin should be able to find this data in tsconfig.json or pachage.json, so it's not needed in eslintrc at all

Comment: Did you mean in eslintrc.json only right? Let me check, because I have same structure in eslintrc.json and package.json for babel included. @Dimava